# How to change the Layout of the IFileSaveDialog - MFC

Tags: windows, visual-c++, layout, mfc

I want to change the Layout of my custom `IFileSaveDialog` in the mfc.

I want to change `Right-to-left` layout for the `IFileSaveDialog` for the `Arabic` Language.

Is their any properties to directly changed?

I dint find any way to do this, Please help me out.

Thanks in Advance.

**Edit**

Need little bit more help, How can I get `CComptr IFileSaveDialog` handle ?

Comment: Is there any properties like `LayoutRTL` that other Dialog has..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that file dialogs do not inherit their layout from the parent window. I was a little surprised by this.

I think you may need to force the issue by adding the `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL` to the dialog window. That's not totally easy to do since the file dialog interface does not provide you a window handle. You can work around that by using a CBT hook.

Here's an example which forces RTL for all dialogs (which have class name `#32770`). I've written the example in Delphi since that's what I am personally most familiar with. I'm sure you can translate it into your MFC environment.

First of all install the hook:

```
hook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, CBTProc, 0, GetCurrentThreadId);
```

And when you need to uninstall it:

```
UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook);
```

And the hook procedure:

```
function CBTProc(nCode: Integer; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
var
  wnd: HWND;
  ClassName: array [0..63] of Char;
  Style: DWORD;
begin
  if nCode=HCBT_ACTIVATE then begin
    wnd := wParam;
    GetClassName(wnd, ClassName, Length(ClassName));
    if ClassName='#32770' then begin
      Style := GetWindowLongPtr(wnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
      SetWindowLongPtr(wnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, Style or WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL);
    end;
  end;
  Result := CallNextHookEx(hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
end;
```

And this is what it looks like on my very left-to-right English OS:

[image]

Comment: Very odd that this is not directly exposed, I don't see it either.  This does look like the best hack.

Comment: Need little bit more help, How can I get `CComptr IFileSaveDialog` handle ?

Comment: It's returned by your call to `CoCreateInstance`.